# Example for a simple Python client and C++ server

Tags: c++, python

Hello -- I need a simple example to help me understand how to write a Python client and C++ server. Can someone help me find an example of how to send `hello world` from a server running C++ to Python client? I tried searching Google and other websites for several hours and couldn't find a single example on how to send a parameter through tcp/ip.

Comment: What transport protocol?

Comment: tcp ip, for terminal of the Operating System of windows thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this http://www.cs.utah.edu/~swalton/listings/sockets/programs/part2/chap6/simple-server.c, It is a simple echo server that accepts connections on port 9999 and echos received message.

For python side this is not very hard, look at this example:

```
import socket, time

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(('localhost', 9999))
print client.send('Hello world!'), 'bytes sent.'
time.sleep(0.2)
print 'Received message:', client.recv(1024)
```

Comment: Thanks you su mutch, only one thing, in the python code import time is necesary for Linux.

Comment: Supplement: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/tutorials/l-pysocks/section3.html OP should read this.

Answer (score 1):

use zeromq lib.. .
c++ example of 'hello_world' for server and client are at :

[http://zguide.zeromq.org/cpp:hwserver](http://zguide.zeromq.org/cpp%3ahwserver)  , 
[http://zguide.zeromq.org/cpp:hwclient](http://zguide.zeromq.org/cpp%3ahwclient)
respectively.. .

and in python.. . study the examples available at github.. .
https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/tree/master/examples

Well for my own purpose i am using python for both end.. .Also for more tutorial watch this pycon video
 http://blip.tv/pycon-us-videos-2009-2010-2011/pycon-2011-advanced-network-architectures-with-zeromq-4896861
also there is another nice tutorial at http://blog.pythonisito.com/2012/08/distributed-systems-with-zeromq.html